# execute javascript function from controller in MVC 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I got an action result inside a controller and i need to display Modals from bootstrap-modal  the problem is... .

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` isn't working like in old asp.net

there is a solution to this? I'm new to mvc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the easiest solution for registering javascript from the controller was quite obvious, but frustrating for someone who's new to the pattern:

Using named sections we find a place for put the javascript

You can use **[Named Sections][1].**

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js)">
    @RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)
</head>
```

and this code for the view

**_SomeView.cshtml**

```
@section JavaScript
{
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.message)
}
```

**and in the controller we return**

```
ViewBag.message = @"<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>alert(""Hello World!"")</script>"; ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC scripts are not registered in controller actions. There's a separation between controllers and views. So you could directly put the script in the corresponding view: